# KeQueryTickCount redundant in X64 ntoskrnl.lib?

Tags: c++, device

I am compiling DisckCryptor code in X64, where in device program KeQueryTickCount is used

```
KeQueryTickCount(&seed.seed21);
```

It requires ntoskrnl.lib to be included.
When I checked what are functions that are exported in ntoskrnl.lib, there is no
KeQueryTickCount routine available.

```
dumpbin /EXPORTS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.15063.0\km\x64\ntoskrnl.lib"
```

when I check the same for X86 it is available

```
dumpbin /EXPORTS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.15063.0\km\x86\ntoskrnl.lib"
```

is KeQueryTickCount depriciated in X64?

If so could you please let me know the function which can replace the KeQueryTickCount routine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just look in the .h file for the declaration, you'll see it is a macro.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, the macro is available in wdm.h, but we have to define _KERNEL_MODE in order to enable the macro.